# Compare buttons for the same image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am new to iOS development and I was trying to make a basic tic tac toe app.
I am not able to find a way to compare the value of three buttons (the ones in a row or column, *etc.*). I managed to create 9 buttons and I am replacing the image of each button on user click (either X or O based on turn). Also I am using tag id from 1-9 on buttons.

Here the code I am facing an error in.

```
func check(){
    let b1 = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton
    let b2 = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as? UIButton
    let b3 = self.view.viewWithTag(3) as? UIButton
    let b4 = self.view.viewWithTag(4) as? UIButton
    let b5 = self.view.viewWithTag(5) as? UIButton
    let b6 = self.view.viewWithTag(6) as? UIButton
    let b7 = self.view.viewWithTag(7) as? UIButton
    let b8 = self.view.viewWithTag(8) as? UIButton
    let b9 = self.view.viewWithTag(9) as? UIButton
    if(b1.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "x")) && b2.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "x")) && b3.currentImage.isEqual(UIImage(named: "x")))
    {
        print("X wins")
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on `if` statement saying:

> Value of optional type 'UIButton?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Now the problem is the inbuilt help is not fixing the error. Also I do not understand why am I getting this error. Can someone help me explain why I am facing this error? Also how to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest you use a simpler model for your board, like an array of `Int` and not try to detect the images of the buttons.

Comment: This is one of the absolute basics of Swift. If you cannot solve this problem yourself, read a book about the Swift language before continuing with development.

Comment: You are likely facing quite a few issues with your code. Some are related to *Swift* development (`as? UIButton` and some are related to *iOS* development (what are you trying to do with the repeated `self.view.viewWithTag(1)` calls). For the former, search on "optional", and "nil" - there are several resources. For the latter, learn about using the tag property that any `UIView` or their iOS subclasses employ.

Comment: Not related but comparing button images with `viewForTag` is very inefficient. Create a model and compare scalar types.

Comment: @dfd it was a mistake. I edited it to correct. Actually I was trying to get the buttons using tag names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let b1 = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton
```

In the above statement b1 is of type UIButton? so in order to use the currentImage property of button you will need a concrete instance of button. To resolve this you can either use if let, guard let or force unwrapping. I am putting an example of guard let below.

```
guard let b1 = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton else {return}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below error means that you are using optional without unwrapping it. If you are sure that buttons exist then force unwrap it or for safe unwrap use `guard` or `if != nil`. See the Apple's documentation for optional as it's important for iOS development.

> Value of optional type 'UIButton?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

And you can compare two buttons using their tag values:

```
if (b1.tag == b2.tag)
{
     code
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/